# Limit of polynomial functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, sequence-of-function

**Problem:** Given a sequence $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of polynomial functions such that $f_n(x)=\sum_{j=0}^{n}\dfrac{j^3}{4^{j+2}}x^j$, find the largest real number $r$, such that $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to a function $f:(0,r)\to\mathbb{R}$ pointwise on $(0,r)$. Also show that $f$ is continuous on $(0,r)$.

**Question:** I was able to show pointwise convergence on the maximal interval $(0,4)$ by treating $(f_n(x))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ as a power series and calculating its radius of convergence. However, I haven't been able to prove that $f$ is continuous on $(0,4)$, as the only thing that came to my mind was to use that polynomial functions are continuous.

Comment: Prove that the convergence is uniform on any $[0,4-\epsilon]$, and use that [uniform limits of continuous functions are continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_limit_theorem).

Comment: @Conifold Thank you, that would basically solve the problem, but I don't really know how I should prove that the convergence is uniform on any $[0,4-\epsilon]$. Is there a particular theorem that is needed for showing this?

Comment: Yes, it is easy to estimate terms of this series as $|f_n(x)|\leq M_n$, where $\sum_nM_n<\infty$, when $|x|\leq R<4$. And a series so estimated converges absolutely and uniformly by the [Weierstrass M-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x\in (0,4)$. Choose $\alpha>0$ with $x+\alpha<4$. Then, for any $y\in (0,4)$ and $m>n$, 
\begin{align}
|f_m(y)-f_n(y)|
&\leq \sum_{k=n+1}^m \frac{k^3}{4^{k+2}}\,|y|^k\\ \ \\
&\leq \sum_{k=n+1}^m \frac{k^3}{4^{k+2}}\,(x+\alpha)^k\\ \ \\
&=\frac1{16} \sum_{k=n+1}^m  {k^3}\,\left(\frac{x+\alpha}4\right)^k\\ \ \\
&=\frac1{16} \sum_{k=n+1}^m  {k^3}\,q^k\\ \ \\
\end{align}
where $q=\tfrac{x+\alpha}4\in(0,1)$. As this last sum is the tail of a convergent series, we get that $\{f_n\}$ is uniformly Cauchy, so its limit is a continuous function on $(0,4)$.

Comment: Thank you, but why does this imply that ${f_n}$ is uniformly Cauchy?

Comment: Because the bound is the same for any $y$. I have edited to remove the small interval, as it was not needed.